Client disconnection not propagated on haproxy
I have a haproxy server to proxy requests to some node js web services. On node I want to detect when clients disconnects because I need to invalidate it's requests on my Redis queue.
If I connect directly to my node server I can detect client disconnection, but if I pass through haproxy the clients seem to be always connected.
I suspect that haproxy does not propagates clients disconnection on server side.
I found some closed issues that declare this problem as fixed, but I tested haproxy 2.6 and 3.0 and the behaviour is the same.
I tried to change different haproxy settings but this issue persists.
All I want is to configure haproxy to let me detect client disconnection from node.
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Finally I found the answer.
For future reference the option to use is:
option abortonclose

This option explicit close server side socket when client disconnect its side.
